# right Div isn't coming inline with left div

Tags: html

I am trying to display a 70/30 ratio blocks on divs but for some reason, they are not coming in line.

I even used `float:left` on left div but then right div gets out of HomeClass border.

http://jsfiddle.net/gdWM5/3/

Code is too much to paste here so created a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gdWM5/13/**

You just need to specify `float:left` on both your left and right divs. Add a dummy div in the container and `clear:both` on it to clear the floats (important).

*Markup*:

```
<div id="Home" class="HomeClass">
    <div id="Left" class="Width70">
        <!-- contents of left div -->
    </div>
    <div id="Right" class="Width30">
        <!-- contents of right div -->
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*:

```
.Width70 {
    float:left;
    ...
}
.Width30 {
    float:left;
    ...
}
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have padding that is not accounted for in your widths. I would advise changing your widths to 69% and 29% accordingly and changing the padding to 1%.

-Edit-

Also, add the `float:left;` to your width70 and width30 classes

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see in your example where you have applied `float:left` but it should be applied to the 'right' object to be floated to the left